# c# TCP Packet loss

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying to send some strings over Network between Server and Client. It works great for small strings(upto ~1400 Bytes) but as soon i send more than ~ 1400 Bytes of data, most of the times i get only 1400 Bytes and data >1400 Bytes get lost.
Hier is my Client code:

```
    public static string Senddata(string BarcodeText)
    {
        try
        {
            string textToSend = BarcodeText.ToString();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);
            //---send the text---
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            return "Success";//if sent
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Fail";//if not sent
        }
    }

    // Recieve Data from Server
    public static string Getdata()
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            str = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
            return str;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Did not recieved anything from Virtual PC";
        }
    }
```

Hier is the code for the Server:

```
    public static string GetDatafromClient()
    {
        try
        {
            //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
            nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            //Console.WriteLine("buffer");
            //---read incoming stream---
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "-";
        }

    }

    public static void SendDatatoClient(string DataToSend)
    {
        FileHandling.SaveToFile(DataToSend);
        //---write back the text to the client---
        byte[] bytesTosend = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(DataToSend);
        nwStream.Write(bytesTosend, 0, bytesTosend.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Does 1400 Bytes happen to be your Buffer size?

Comment: As asked by @Fildor.... looks like client.ReceiveBufferSize is 1400?

Comment: No, it is default. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Asked because when receiving, you read at most 1 buffer size of data. All in all this is a suboptimal way to send/receive data of unknown length. You'd be better off coming up with some kind of protocol, so you can read continuously and break input into data chunks by detecting delimiters defined by your protocol. OR use some existing protocol.

Comment: _"No, it is default."_ - As in "I didn't change it" or in "I checked and it is the same as the default"?

Comment: Also note that one call to `Read` may return less bytes than the _size_ param: _"The Read operation reads **as much data as is available**, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter."_

Comment: Yes, I tried to increase the buffer size upto 1 MB but same problem is happening .

Comment: try to put the read in a loop until `bytesRead` returns 0 and accumulate the results.

Comment: TCP is an *endless stream of bytes in both directions*. It's not *messaging*. There's no guarantee (as you've discovered) that each call to `Write` on one side will be matched 1-1 with a call to `Read` at the other. If you want *messaging*, it's up to *you* to implement it atop TCP or to move to a higher level protocol that implements it for you. A typical simple way to implement messaging is to prefix each message by sending its *length*. You can then, as others have said, *loop* until you know you've received all bytes. (Note that even the length may be fragmented if its more than 1 byte)

Comment: Doesn't each `GetStream()` instantiate a new `NetworkStream` with its own buffer, which snoops bytes off of the socket?

Comment: No, it doesnt..

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for helping me . I resolved this issue by myself and posted answer also.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for helping me . I resolved this issue by myself and posted answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved this issue by sending first 4 bytes as a data length and then the actual data and i am getting 0 data loss now. Thank you all guys for tying to help me. The client side looks like:

```
        public static string Getdata()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] DataLengthinBytes = new byte[4];
            nwStream.Read(DataLengthinBytes, 0, 4);
            int DataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(DataLengthinBytes, 0);
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[DataLength];
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while(i < DataLength){
                bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, DataLength);
                str.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
                i += bytesRead;
            }
            return str.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Did not recieved anything from Virtual PC";
        }
    }
```

and the server side:

```
        public static void SendDatatoClient(string DataToSend)
    {
        //---write back the text to the client---
        byte[] bytesTosend = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(DataToSend);
        byte[] Datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)bytesTosend.Length);
        nwStream.Write(Datalength, 0, 4);
        nwStream.Write(bytesTosend, 0, bytesTosend.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Why use ISO-8859-1 instead of a unicode encoding? (Though when using UTF-8/16 you need to first read all bytes in a message and then convert, to ensure you don't stumble over split multi-byte encoded codepoints)

Comment: Also, your code is buggy. Consider the case where reading the length doesn't read the full 4 bytes.

Comment: I used ISO-8859-1 for german special characters. Yeah, I know that something can go wrong while reading first 4 Bytes thatswhy i am using an another "while". If i will use "while" it may happen that i will end up reading first byte of Data also if 1 byte from data.length will get lost. To be safe, i should higher level protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a loop as in the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Examples for CanRead, Read, and DataAvailable.

// Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable.
if(myNetworkStream.CanRead){
    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

    // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
    do
    {
        numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
    }
    while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);

    // Print out the received message to the console.
    Console.WriteLine("You received the following message : " + myCompleteMessage);

    else{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.");
}
```

The problem is maybe that your data is sent in more than one "package". There are many ways to solve this. The [Length byte](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joncole/2006/03/20/simple-message-framing-sample-for-tcp-socket/) is one of them. Another solution is to use framing bytes. -> you put your data between this bytes so you know the start and end -> 0x02  data 0x03.

In the long run it's maybe simpler to use a high level protocol such as [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api).

Comment: Thanks dude. I did not work for me but it did help me. I posted the solution down and now i am getting 0 % Packet loss.

Comment: WTF that example is so horrible. The only reason to use `DataAvailable` as the loop condition is to make the code non blocking, but since the condition is after the first read call, it can still block.